# How do I make my pathfinding algorithm highlight the shortest path?

Tags: path, processing, visualization, shortest

I've been programming in Java for about 4 months now and I have finally managed to create an A* pathfinding visualization. I used the 'Porcessing' library, and although I'm sure that my code isn't too good and unsure if I implemented it perfectly - it appears to work! :D
My issue right now is that my code doesn't highlight the best path, it just draws a big black stain on the grid (the big black stain is the 'player'). How could I make the program highlight the shortest path?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can hardly help you without seeing your code. In general, you have to somehow what step to take next. From there on it is just a task to "highlight" the next step one-by-one until the goal is reached.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the answer! I'm just still a bit confused regarding how to check what should be the next step.
I'll upload my code to GitHub and then share the link when I get home.